# DateTime.Parse doesn't use patterns in current CultureInfo(Silverlight)?

Tags: c#, datetime, silverlight-4.0, localization, cultureinfo

I've got following problem. 
I set `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` and use following patterns in them:

`ShortDatePattern` is `dd-MM-yyyy`

LongTimePattern is `HH.mm.ss`.

When I convert dates to string I get `15-01-2008 00.00.00`. But when i call `DateTime.Parse("15-01-2008 00.00.00")` it throws a `FormatException`. If i set `ShortDatePattern` to  `dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss` exception is still thrown. Is there any way to force `DateTime.Parse` to use pattern for time by setting `CurrentCulture` accordingly.

I know that using Parse overloads or `ParseExact` might help, but the whole point was to use formatting without `refactoring` loads of code that is already written and uses `DateTime.Parse` and `ToString` all over the place

**Additional info:** A also tried putting `-` and `.` in `'` - it was no use. `CurrentCulture` is based on `Swedish`.

Comment: @nowRave, are you looking to get all of the DateTime values in your application set as ShortDate..? I have provided and answer but someone wanted to know if you wanted to format vs doing DateTime.Parse please look at the solution and verify..

Comment: Yeah, i updated my question. I forgot to mention that i wanted to use not only DateTime.Parse, but DateTime.ToString as well, since we have a lot of code written. While ToString() uses pattern i set without questions, Parse ignores is for whatever reason so string value i get from DateTime.ToString has "Invalid" format according to DateTime.Parse . So the question is strictly about forcing DateTime.Parse to parse strings with time in following format `HH.mm.ss`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to format a DateTIme using `String.Format()` Method you could do something like this below. [String.Format DateTime C#](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
 var dt = "15-01-2008 00.00.00";
 var dateFrmt = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt);
```

`Output = "15-01-2008 00.00.00"`

if you want to strip the HH:mm:ss out of the DateTime variable for short date you could do the following here is an example will yield ShortDate

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
 var dateFrmt = String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);
```

`Output = "1/9/2013"`

[DateTime.ParseExact Method if you choose to go that route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure he wants to format dates rather than parsing them?

Comment: based on what he wanted It seemed that what he was doing worked for DateTime but when trying to Parse the DateTime value to get ShortDate, it caused an error, so formatting his date to return only Short Date the second example would work for him.. I have tested both